# Pra que server a função history.pushState?

Tags: html5, html5-history

Percebi que o objeto `history` tem alguma relação com manipulação de histórico do navegador. Há métodos como `go` e `back` que são mais compreensíveis, porém não entendo muito bem o que faz a função `pushState`.

Qual é a finalidade de `history.pushState`?

Comment: A função pushState do objeto History do javascript serve para mudar a url do browser sem dar Refresh. Altera a url sem recarregar a página, Veja mais em http://www.tidbits.com.br/pushstate-no-html-pra-mudar-a-url-do-browser-sem-dar-refresh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Como construir sites que se aproveitam dos princípios do AJAX, enquanto continuam a ser acessíveis aos mecanismos de busca?

> **Resposta:** uma função Javascript que faz parte da ‘API History do HTML5’, chamada window.history.pushState().
> A função pushState do objeto History do javascript serve para mudar a url do browser sem dar Refresh. Altera a url sem recarregar a página,

Sempre que você abre uma nova aba e/ou janela, o navegador inicia uma nova sessão. E é nesta sessão que ele armazena todas as URL’s que você visitou.

O método pushState registra uma nova entrada no seu histórico de sessão, mantendo o histórico. E essa é a sua sintaxe:

```
window.history.pushState(data, title [, url ] )
```

`data`: O parâmetro `data` pode ser útil caso você queira utilizar o evento onPopState, que é invocado sempre que uma nova entrada é registrada no seu histórico de sessão;

`Title`: É o título da página que você quer que a entrada tenha;

`URL`: É a URL que você quer que a página tenha. Você pode utilizar este parametro de duas formas:

- Absoluta: Passando toda a nova URL completa, incluindo protocolo, host, path etc. Ex: http://blog.igorescobar.com/;
- Relativa: A URL que você passar, será relativa a URL atual, ou seja, se você estiver acessando o http://blog.igorescobar.com/ e passar “/category/javascript/” a URL que será registrada é “http://blog.igorescobar.com/category/javascript/”.

Exemplo:

```
window.history.pushState('Object', 'Categoria JavaScript', '/category/javascript/');
```

### Conclusão

Agora com a utilização do HTML5 podemos criar sites com AJAX indexáveis pelos mecanismos de busca sem problemas. Nosso [Link Building](https://moz.com/blog/category/link-building)  não será comprometido e a experiência do usuário pode ser aprimorada ainda mais, uma vez que, apenas uma fração do código entregue é realmente o conteúdo.

[**exemplo - JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/udu3bw38/)